# How to make a grid like layout in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to make a layout that has three buttons (same width on each one) in a horizontal line.

```
xxxx   xxxx   xxxx
xxxx   xxxx   xxxx
```

X represents the button. How can I distribute 33 % to each cell, then add a button inside it which does NOT stretch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use a [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout), with `android:layout_weight="1"`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button 3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a [`TableLayout`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#tablelayout): 3 columns, 2 rows, a stretchMode of `spacingWidthUniform`.

EDIT: haven't tried it, but this should work;

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Settings"
                android:id="@+id/btnSettings"></Button>
            <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
            <Button android:text="@+id/Button02" android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow02" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:text="@+id/Button03" android:id="@+id/Button03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
            <Button android:text="@+id/Button04" android:id="@+id/Button04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
            <Button android:text="@+id/Button05" android:id="@+id/Button05"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```